# When to throw exceptions for constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor, nullpointerexception

```
public Neocortex(Region rootRegion, ConnectionInterface functor) {
this.rootRegion = rootRegion;
this.currentRegion = this.rootRegion;
this.functor = functor;
}
```

Hey above I have the constructor for one of my classes. My question is should I add null pointer exceptions to the constructor or would this be unnecessary? Honestly, I just don't understand when I should add exceptions to my code. But in this case which constructor should i use?

```
public Neocortex(Region rootRegion, ConnectionInterface functor) {
    if (rootRegion == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("rootRegion cannot be null");
} else if (functor == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("functor cannot be null");
    }
this.rootRegion = rootRegion;
this.currentRegion = this.rootRegion;
this.functor = functor;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... It is a matter of taste.

If the preconconditions for the class is that rootRegion has to be provided, it makes sense to protect the class implementation from the need to make null checks all over the place.

So to answer the question "When should I throw exception in a constructor" : I would do it in all cases where the parameters, from the consumer, brings your implementation in a invalid state, delegate the problem (ie. throw the exception).

If you try to take the role as consumer for a while, and you choose not to make the null-checks he will have code like:

```
Neocortex n = new Neocortex(null,null);
n.doSomeething();
```

If he reach the 2nd line, and the implementation here throws a NullPointerException it will not be clear for him that it is due to the parameters he provided.

Answer (score 3):

I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for those arguments to the constructor that, if accepted, would lead to something bad (including, but not limited to, a `null` argument).  That is, it would lead to the completed construction of an object that doesn't make sense.

Don't throw a `NullPointerException`, because you haven't attempted to call a method on something `null` yet.

From the [`IllegalArgumentException` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

And if `null` is inappropriate, then throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: *"Don't throw a NullPointerException, because you haven't attempted to call a method on something null yet."* It's perfectly valid to throw `NullPointerException` for any inappropriate use of `null`, not just attempts to dereference it. See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). In fact, they say you "*should*" do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, it may be valid, but in my opinion, `IllegalArgumentException` is clearer.  I always think that `null` was dereferenced if a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: I would tend to favor distinguishing cases where a method (or constructor) is expected to operate on a passed-in *object*, from those which are expected to operate on the *reference* without regard for what it's pointing to (e.g. a queue with a `GetNextItem` method that returns null when no more data exists might not allow null references to be enqueued, but wouldn't be expected to dereference a passed-in item).  Throwing NPE in the latter scenario would be unexpected, but in the former scenario not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `null` is not an acceptable value for `rootRegion`, etc., then throw `NullPointerException` from the constructor. From the [`NullPointerException` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), where it talks about when the JVM will throw this, but also says:

> Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the `null` object.

You *could* use `IllegalArgumentException` for the more general case of arguments that aren't valid for the constructor, but `NullPointerException` is exactly right for the case of an argument being `null` that ought not be. `IllegalArgumentException` does have the advantage, though, of being pretty darned clear about what's wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case I'd throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, which means a lot more to the user of your class than a `NullPointerException`.

It is not a bad practice to have constructors throw exceptions. However, you should make sure that they are well documented (especially in the case of runtime exceptions), and meaningful to the caller.